# m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle

Tags: c#, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I've been wrestling with a problem, maybe you guys can point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to digitally sign a pdf, on the webserver, over an https connection.

At page load i'm doing as so:

```
HttpClientCertificate cs = Request.ClientCertificate;
X509Certificate card = new X509Certificate(cs.Certificate);
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
 Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { cp.ReadCertificate(card.GetRawCertData())};
```

I'm getting the error "m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle" at that last line of code.

Please note that:

- I am getting the same error using 2 completely different certificates.
- The certificate is being retrieved to the "card" variable ok.
- I used to get the card to X509Certificate2 but i read yesterday somewhere I'm not being able to find that the error could be solved by casting as a X509Certificate and then downcasting to X509Certificate2. It was one of those "well... this does not makes any sense but i havent tried it yet" moments.
- I have tried to add `[System.Security.SecurityCritical, System.Security.SecurityTreatAsSafe]` property to all methods and even the class to see if it would work... no such luck.

Can anyone one give me a hint?

Comment: I had similar issue, then i realised that i was disposing off the certificate before it gets used. could you check if your certificate is not directly or indirectly getting disposed before it gets used.

Comment: @Gurpreet; your comment helped me, I think, and I was using a 'using' statement in an Asp.net Core Startup.cs file (and nothing to do with signing pdfs)

Answer (score 17):

This can happen any time you access uninitialized fields in cryptography.

In your code, if `Request.ClientCertificate` returns an object with no raw certificate data then you will see the error when you call `card.GetRawCertData()` on your fourth line.

As a simple test, try the following:

```
var cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2();
Console.WriteLine(cert.Thumbprint);
```

This will throw the following exception because there is no thumbprint available:

```
m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle.
```

with the given stack trace:

```
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.ThrowIfContextInvalid()
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.SetThumbprint()
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.GetCertHashString()
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_Thumbprint()
at MyEncryptionUtility.EncryptionUtilityForm.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\MyEncryptionUtility\EncryptionUtilityForm.cs:line 2864
```

Comment: I'm calling `.HasPrivateKey` and getting the same error. So it is not initialized. so how to check if it has a private key?

Comment: I'm not sure @AaA . I'd try asking that as a new question here.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is not your problem, but for others: make sure you don't call X509Certificate2.Reset() before trying to access any certificate related properties or methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public bool ReadCertFromSignedFile(X509Certificate2 cert, string filename)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filename) && File.Exists(filename))
        {
            var cert509 = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(filename);
            cert = new X509Certificate2(cert509.GetRawCertData());

            return CheckSertificate(cert);
        }
        else
        { throw new Exception("Сертификат не заполнен"); }
    }
```

method calling from another code like this

```
   if (_digitalSignatureService.ReadCertFromSignedFile(fileCert, file.SignFilePath))
                 {
                    if (!cert.Equals(fileCert))
                    {
```

Equals - calling error "m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle." because  X509Certificate not exist

decision

```
 public bool ReadCertFromSignedFile(X509Certificate2 cert, string filename)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filename) && File.Exists(filename))
        {
            var cert509 = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(filename);

            cert.Import(cert509.GetRawCertData());
```

this code works!