# Is it possible to store RSACryptoServiceProvider in X509Certificate2 or X509Store?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have keypair provided to me by hardware device in form of `RSAParameters`
which I can convert to a `CryptoServiceProvider` using following code and encrypt/decrypt/sign.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAPrivKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048) { PersistKeyInCsp = false };
// RSAParameters rsaparam = RSAPrivKey.ExportParameters(true); // for testing
RSAPrivKey.ImportParameters(rsaparam);
```

I'm not allowed to use file system to store the certificate and as hardware device is not available sometimes, I like to store this certificate in Machine Certificate store `(Certificates -> Local Computer -> personal)`

As the `X509Certificate2.PrivateKey` [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.privatekey(v=vs.100).aspx) suggests, I should be able to set private key of the certificate and save it to store like following

```
X509Certificate2 Cert2 = new X509Certificate2();
Cert2.PrivateKey = RSAPrivKey;

X509Store cstore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
cstore.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
cstore.Add(Cert2);
cstore.Close();
```

However I get error `m_safeCertContext is an invalid handle` which according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130453/1041046) is happening because some properties of `X509Certificate2` are not set, which is correct. I cannot assign validity date, issuer, ... to the certificate.

**Question**

Is it even possible to store `RSACryptoServiceProvider` in `X509Certificate2`? If yes, am I missing some steps?